# TYPO3: nested entities in TCA

Tags: typo3, extbase

For a new extension in Typo3 i need to know how the functionality seen in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h47UU.png) can be realised in TCA and how to implement it? It would be great to know how it is called. Icant find it anywhere and i think this is a core functionality because the same feature is used in TemplaVoila too. The current installed Typo3 Version is 4.5 (LTS). I have no idea how to start. Please help me.

best regards
flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is called [Inline Relational Record Editing](http://wiki.typo3.org/Inline_Relational_Record_Editing), short IRRE. The TCA-type is "[inline](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Inline/Index.html)".